# How to improve speed of dart function?

Tags: performance, dart, flutter

I just started to programm a game in flutter, but i have the problem, that the method use is very slow, about 6 seconds with 4 Players. I want to improve that.

What i did so far:

- Make everything async, and wait for it at the end, but i don't kown why, it does not improve the speed. At least not so much that you can feel it.

Good would be when this method runs in under a second. But i have not ideas how to improve the speed anymore.

Thats the code:

```
Future nextRound(
  ChatMessageRound chatMessageRound, String gamePlayId, Chat chat) async {
if (chatMessageRound.getWinner().length <= 0)
  throw NoWinnerMarkedException();
var futures = List<Future>();
var gamePlay =
    await _chatRepository.getGamePlayRepository(chat.id).get(gamePlayId);

var winnerIds = ListBuilder<String>(
    gamePlay.winnerIds.toList(growable: true)
      ..addAll(chatMessageRound.getWinner()));
var chatMessageGameRoundIds = ListBuilder<String>(
    gamePlay.chatMessageGameRoundIds.toList(growable: true)
      ..add(chatMessageRound.id));
gamePlay = gamePlay.rebuild((builder) {
  builder.winnerIds = winnerIds;
  builder.chatMessageGameRoundIds = chatMessageGameRoundIds;
});

var newChatMessageRound =
    chatMessageRound.rebuild((builder) => builder.disabled = true);
futures.add(_chatRepository
    .getChatMessagesRepository(chat.id)
    .update(newChatMessageRound));

if (gamePlay.chatMessageGameRoundIds.length >=
    _remoteConfigRepository.gamesToPlayCount()) {
  var player = getPlayer(chat, gamePlay.playerIds);
  var scoreMembers = player.map((member) {
    return ChatMessageScoreUserInfo((builder) {
      builder.name = member.name;
      builder.profilePictureUrl = member.profilePictureDownloadUrl;
      builder.userId = member.userId;
      builder.score = gamePlay.winnerIds
          .where((winnerId) => winnerId == member.userId)
          .length;
    });
  });

  for (var player in scoreMembers) {
    futures.add(Future<dynamic>(() async {
      var user = await getUser(player.userId);
      user = user.rebuild((builder) {
        builder.points = builder.points + player.score;
      });
      await updateUser(user);
    }));
  }

  var chatMessageScore = ChatMessageScore((builder) {
    builder.scorePossible = _remoteConfigRepository.gamesToPlayCount();
    builder.members = ListBuilder(scoreMembers);
  });

  futures.add(_chatRepository
      .getChatMessagesRepository(chat.id)
      .add(chatMessageScore));
} else {
  futures.add(
      startRound(chat, gamePlay.playerIds, previousGamePlay: gamePlay));
}
futures
    .add(_chatRepository.getGamePlayRepository(chat.id).update(gamePlay));
await Future.wait<dynamic>(futures);
}
```

My database is firestore. If you need more details, then write a comment.

Comment: Use https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging#dart-observatory-statement-level-single-stepping-debugger-and-profiler to track down what parts of your code use up the time.

Comment: Are you running under debug or release mode? You might wanna test performance related stuff on release mode as debug is not optimised for performance and is also known as "slow mode".

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That's the problem, if i start observatory, i get a blank page.

Comment: @SnakeyHips On release, i takes 4 Seconds, but still to much

Comment: There's really no way to help you improve the performance when your code cannot be run by anyone else... It would be helpful if you could create a 
 MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Ringil With observatory i mean this: https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging#tracing-any-dart-code-performance